# Jasper Reports adds a surprising newline

Tags: jasper-reports

In the attached, we see a Jasper report with two text columns.  The rows are populated from a single coherent data structure.  This is the bottom of a table, and we can see a strange dangling "S".  This is the last letter of the preceding UNKNOWN. The data is actually "UNKNOWNS".

[image]

In fact, every UNKNOWN in this table has a dangling S, you just can't see it unless you highlight the report (like when you select for copy/paste).  I have checked the UNKNOWNS text in the data set character by character. There are no shenanigans with embedded Unicode or tricky newlines. It's just 8 ASCII characters.

The report is 1,300 pages long. No other value yields dangling letters except for "UNKNOWNS" (*edit - the rows with CMOP in that column break too. A newline is being inserted before the P*).  As you see here, the column is plenty wide, and there are wider values (like "VOLUNTARY TIMEKEEPING") that don't get split up.

I also added logic so that if the column's value begins with UNKN then I slam a hardcoded "UNKNOWNS" into the table. It splits and dangles like like the real data from the data structure.

EDIT - I was slamming UNKNOWNS into the table but decided to slam UNKNOWN instead. This happens now:

[image]

Note that I selected the output (it's a PDF at this point) to show how the N now dangles.

How can such a specific error be happening? I'm wondering is UNKNOWNS is a reserved word or something.

EDIT - I wrote the report as HTML so we could see if the issue is related to PDF generation.

From this screen cap, it looks like the HTML output is ok.

[image]

From an examination of the html source, we can confirm there are no odd characters in UNKNOWNS

[image]

EDIT 2 - As an experiment, I modified the work UNKNOWNS so each time I used it, a letter would be replaced by the letter X.  This is the result:

[image]

We can see from this that Jasper is inserting an extraneous newline in all cases except one. For some reason, it likes `UNKNOXNS`.

For completeness, here's a jrxml snippet for that column in the report. As I said before, some output values are longer, some are shorter.  The only values that break are UNKNOWNS and CMOP, and they break every time.

[image]

EDIT 2 - Per @Halfer's suggestion, I changed the font.  And now this PDF snippet... which is **not** insane. A glimmer of hope!  `CMOP` behaves also.

[image]

Comment: Does Jasper Reports have a preview function (e.g. in a desktop app) so you can see if this happens before it gets turned into a PDF?

Comment: @halfer no this is happening on a server. However, I changed the code to output an HTML file. Now we can see if it is related to PDF generation.

Comment: post has been edited

Comment: Could you try a different font? Maybe there is a kerning fault in the font you're using.

Comment: Failing that, this is not really my bag - maybe add a bounty on the question to get some more eyeballs on it.

Comment: Ah, following the update, maybe you are using a default generic font e.g. "sans-serif" and your system default on the server is something that is not particularly great quality. See if you can find out what font it is using, and then use a named font. Even if you have to license Arial or Verdana on a Linux server, it may be worth the price.

Comment: @KJ Well where font names are concerned, spelling counts.  Since fixing that, something has gone all wrong and now no font names are recognized. For example, "Helvetica" is being rejected. Blah.

Comment: @KJ I'm in a secured managed environment. I can't get any code out. That's why I posted caps.